# A Chromium line process source on task manager

Tags: chromium, task-management

I have Chromium browser installed on Ubuntu 18.04.

In task manager there's a line about Chromium browser which I want to know if it's normal or not, the line is:

```
--type=utility --utility-sub-type=network.mojom.NetworkService --field-trial-handle=1441856381286841073,7865066266003832000,131072 --lang=fr --service-sandbox-type=network --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's perfectly normal considering Chromium is a snap.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help, it is not a snap package, i install a '.deb' package of chromium wich i downloaded from 'launchpad.com' site, so is this line process normal? Thanks.

Comment: It IS a snap because what you installed is merely a dummy transitional packet that install the snap version, the same as directly installed from the Ubuntu repository.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help, is this line process safe? Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you concern about?

Comment: And for reference (with links): https://askubuntu.com/a/1410690/1210606